# Backbone and Coffeescript "this" reference issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a problem with the "this" reference on Backbone with Coffeescript, this is a method which shows information of an artist:

```
show: (id) ->
    self = @
    if @collection
        artist = @collection.get(id)
        @renderArtist(artist)
    else
        artist = new DemoBackbone.Models.Artist({id: id})
        artist.fetch
            success: ->
                self.renderArtist(artist)

renderArtist: (artist) ->
    view = new DemoBackbone.Views.ArtistsShow(model: artist)
    $('#content_artists').html(view.render().el)
```

This works perfectly, but I'm using the "self = @" statement so I can use the Class function "renderArtist", but is there a more "elegant" way to do this on "success: -> self.renderArtist(artist)", so I can avoid using the "self = @" line??

Something like

```
success: @->
    @renderArtist(artist)
```

I'm not pretty sure but I think there should be a way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the [double-arrow function](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) in CoffeeScript does. It will generate code like you have shown for you automatically so you don't have to write it yourself.

```
success: =>
    @renderArtist(artist)
```